# Remove gaps between items

Tags: memoir

I have several parts of a document which have the following structure:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{preamble}
\begin{document}    
\begin{flushleft}
    \textbf{XYZ COMPANY,} Somewhere, USA\\
    \textbf{Some Position}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{raggedleft}\hfill \hfill Jan 2017 - May 2017\\
    \end{raggedleft}
    \begin{itemize}
    \tightlist
    \item
      Item 1
    \item
      Item 2
    \item
      Item 3
    \end{itemize}
\begin{flushleft}
    \textbf{XYZ COMPANY,} Somewhere, USA\\
    \textbf{Some Position}
    \end{flushleft}
    \begin{raggedleft}\hfill \hfill Jan 2017 - May 2017\\
    \end{raggedleft}
    \begin{itemize}
    \tightlist
    \item
      Item 1
    \item
      Item 2
    \item
      Item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I would like to keep the overall length to 1 page, single-spaced, but have sizeable gaps between each of these blocks. Is this a function of Memoir and if so, how should this behavior be overwritten?

[image: example]

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Updated. See above.

Comment: Do you mean the space between the date and the begin of the list?

Comment: Exactly. A function of `\tightlist`, perhaps?

Comment: `\tightlist` decreases the space inside of your list. The space comes mainly from the line with your date which is empty on the left side.

Comment: My suggestion would be to write the date on the same line as "Some position"

Comment: Multicol package may help.

Comment: There is space above and below the flushleft end plus the blank half line from the date. I'd just make the name and date part as two parboxes or minipages on the same line, aligned on the top or bottom line if the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `article` and some help from [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to keep the lists tight:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\companydetails}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} l @{} }
    \strut #1
  \end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\companyduration}[1]{%
  \hfill
  \strut #1
}

\begin{document}    

\companydetails{%
  \textbf{XYZ COMPANY}, Somewhere, USA \\
  \textbf{Some Position}
}%
\companyduration{Jan 2017 -- May 2017}

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\companydetails{%
  \textbf{XYZ COMPANY}, Somewhere, USA \\
  \textbf{Some Position}
}%
\companyduration{Jan 2017 -- May 2017}

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still have a few things to clean up, but this addresses the alignment issues nicely. Thanks, @Werner.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about memoir. But you may try to use multicol package.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}    
 \begin{flushleft}
  \textbf{XYZ COMPANY,} Somewhere, USA\\
  \textbf{Some Position}
 \end{flushleft}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{itemize}
   \tightlist
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
   \item Item 3
  \end{itemize}
 \columnbreak
  \begin{raggedleft}\hfill \hfill Jan 2017 - May 2017\\
  \end{raggedleft}
 \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```